# iOS NSData logs null value while sending PNS device token

Tags: ios, push-notification, nsdata, apple-push-notifications

i'm enabling PNS service for my app...when i tried to log my NSData value which i'm sending it to my server it logs null.If i use same code for ibaction in my VC it works fine, where if i manually entered the device token..Here is my code...Any idea to solve my issue?...

```
NSString* newToken = [deviceToken description];
newToken = [newToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
newToken = [newToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://sample.net/demo/registerDevice.php?appId=0003&deviceToken=%@",newToken];
NSLog(@"%@",newToken);
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 NSData *urlData ;
NSURLResponse *response ;
urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",urlData);
```

Comment: You should use the `error` parameter of `sendSynchronousRequest` to see why the request failed.